# How can I change the startup directory of my Terminal on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

I want my terminal to always start at a certain directory instead of home. How can I do this?

Comment: I've answered this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39255856/359532

Comment: @Sheehan Scott's answer should be the selected answer, as it is a specific feature within the Terminal app just for this sort of thing, and easy to find.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure if theres a cleaner way, but adding `cd path/to/directory` in your `.bash_profile` in your home directory should automatically change your directory to what you specify.

Comment: As Randolph pointed out, there a cleaner way to change the home directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145321/how-to-set-os-x-terminals-default-home/145330#145330 difference of doing it so is that it also changes what **~** points to, as anything else pointing to "home" and not just the startup place. So, your answer is the most appropriate one for this question with this choice of words.

Comment: If you have "New Windows Open With: Same Working Directory" this will not work. Learned that the hard way.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky What do you suggest then?

Comment: @Volatil3 It's been a while, but since answers like these didn't work for me I came up with my own solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696757/set-the-default-directory-in-mac-terminal/39255856#39255856

Answer (score 13):

In Terminal.app's preferences, in the "Settings" tab, select the style of your terminal (probably Basic: the default), then go to the "Shell" pane and put `cd /any/directory/you/want` in the run command box. This will automatically change directory when you open a new terminal.

Comment: on opening new tab it will not retain the last opening directory

Answer (score 0):

See this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145321/how-to-set-os-x-terminals-default-home) question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
export HOME=DESTINATION_DIRECTORY
```

without any double quotation marks. To verify, type `env` and look out for HOME in the list.

Comment: This does work, but since it changes my HOME, using `cd` will bring it back there and my prompt shows ~ for when I'm in the new HOME. Just letting others know.

Comment: This is highly likely to cause problems. It's common for other scripts and applications to put documents and config files in the user's home folder, which you've just reassigned. If you just want to save yourself some typing when you open the terminal, this isn't the way to do it.